# I'm having an error running 'pod install' after having 'ejected' an expo project

Tags: ios, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

```
Installing unimodules:
 expo-app-auth@10.2.2 from ../node_modules/expo-app-auth/ios
 expo-application@3.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-application/ios
 expo-barcode-scanner@10.2.2 from ../node_modules/expo-barcode-scanner/ios
 expo-constants@11.0.2 from ../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/node_modules/expo-constants/ios
 expo-error-recovery@2.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-error-recovery/ios
 expo-facebook@11.3.1 from ../node_modules/expo-facebook/ios
 expo-file-system@11.1.3 from ../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios
 expo-font@9.2.1 from ../node_modules/expo-font/ios
 expo-image-loader@2.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios
 expo-image-picker@10.2.2 from ../node_modules/expo-image-picker/ios
 expo-keep-awake@9.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios
 expo-location@12.1.2 from ../node_modules/expo-location/ios
 expo-modules-core@0.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios
 expo-permissions@12.1.1 from ../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios
 expo-splash-screen@0.11.4 from ../node_modules/expo-splash-screen/ios
 expo-structured-headers@1.1.1 from ../node_modules/expo-structured-headers/ios
 expo-updates@0.8.5 from ../node_modules/expo-updates/ios
 expo-updates-interface@0.2.2 from ../node_modules/expo-updates-interface/ios
 unimodules-app-loader@2.2.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/ios
 unimodules-core@7.1.2 from ../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@6.3.9 from ../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@6.2.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios

Found some duplicated unimodule packages. Installed the ones with the highest version number.
Make sure following dependencies of your project are resolving to one specific version:
 expo-constants, unimodules-react-native-adapter, unimodules-core

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `appalm`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNFS, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, react-native-fetch-blob, react-native-maps, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-webview, and stripe-react-native
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command
```

/usr/local/bin/pod install

```
### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack
```

CocoaPods : 1.11.2
Ruby : ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
Host : macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Xcode : 13.1 (13A1030d)
Git : git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

```
### Plugins
```

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

````
### Podfile

```ruby
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'appalm' do
  use_unimodules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!('Flipper' => '0.75.1', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1')
  #   post_install do |installer|
  #     flipper_post_install(installer)
  #   end
  # end
end
````

#### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:284:in `ensure_versions_file_loaded'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:208:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.4%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+tried%3A+%27%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.4%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64e%27%29%29%2C+%27%2Fusr%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28no+such+file%29+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.4%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

[!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `ED137CF7B90C44E29996C133` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.```

someone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when running pod install on Mac M1.

It looks like you are using the default ruby that comes with Mac OS and installing some library with Rosetta mode (x86_64). At this time, we can use native M1 for installing libraries.

In my case, following these steps have me solve this problem:

- Uninstall current ruby: `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ruby`
- Show installed cocoapods: `gem list --local | grep cocoapods` . It will show a list of cocoapods installed in your computer.
- Uninstall each cocoapods showed step above: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`, `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core`, ...
- Install ruby with brew: `brew install ruby`
- Recheck ruby is using: `gem env`. In my case, all lines have ruby version 3 from brew
- Install ffi without arch x86_64 or Rosetta: `sudo gem install ffi`
- Install cocoapods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Make sure you exported PATH in your environment. I'm using zsh:

- open file config: `open ~/.zshrc`
- add these lines:

```
if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi
```

- save the file and make it effective: `source ~/.zshrc`

Hope it will help someone face this problem